# Cloudflare wget works, but curl and nodejs fail with 403

Tags: curl, wget

I have a website that i would like to download, but somehow only `wget` (and the browser itself) work, but other things like `curl` (or nodejs `https.get`) do not and fail with `403 Forbidden`

Wget output (works):

```
GET /path HTTP/1.1
Host: somesite.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:102.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/102.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: identity
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Curl output (403):

```
> GET /path HTTP/2
> Host: somesite.com
> accept: */*
> user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:102.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/102.0
```

Firefox output (works):

```
GET /path HTTP/2
Host: somesite.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:102.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/102.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
```

NodeJS (403):

```
GET /path HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:102.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/102.0
Host: somesite.com
Connection: close
```

I have already tried:

- setting `Connection` to `Keep-Alive` on all tools
- copying all headers from firefox to the tools

Edit, i forgot to include some things:

- there is no known proxy in-between
- i have also tried using `-c cookies` for curl, but from what i can tell, no cookies are involved

I have not tried to re-order headers, because i dont know how i could force the order in curl or nodejs and i also have not tried to force casing because of the same reason.

System: Manjaro 21.3.2

PS: all tools use the same url

Comment: This question cannot be replicated without knowing the site. There are multiple factors that could lead to status code 403. Are you using a proxy to verify that there are no changes in headers? This is particularly important in nodejs. curl can be trusted, though. Don't forget to change headers **and** the protocol when running your tests.

Comment: Thanks, i forgot to include (i will also update the question), there is no (to me known) proxy inbetween and the protocol from what i can tell is always https + with tls

Comment: It's "normal"... Cloudflare filters out many clients it considers "bots". User agent, TLS fingerprinting, ...

Comment: @hasezoey by "protocol", I was referring to "HTTP/1.1" vs "HTTP/2", as it affects the way in which headers are parsed.

Comment: @frostschutz It is not "normal" that requests with wget are accepted but requests sent with curl are denied. In fact, Cloudfare's own site allows requests sent with curl.